enabling ssl certificate to aws ec2 instance
if we run an aws ec2 instance and set the inbound rule to access certain port, then running an app on that port (like 0.0.0.0:3000) enables us to access the app from the public ipv4 address of the instance (like 3.135.222.337:3000). running some apis, or webapps in that port can be then accessed from http://3.135.222.337:3000. How to enable ssl certificate to this address? like https://3.135.222.337:3000. using nginx, or anything.
(enabling ssl certificate to public ip addess is possible: Is it possible to have SSL certificate for IP address, not domain name?)

I created a self-signed certificate through nginx, I'll share, how I did it, it solved the initial problem that the browser wasn't letting me record audio, but it also shows not secure, so thinking about better approach

You won't be able to create get a cert backed by a major CA for an EC2 IP.  Part of the baseline requirements to get a cert is to prove ownership of the thing being signed, and you do not own the AWS IP address.  You can register a domain name, and get a cert for that.

I thought about that, but also got the stupid thinking about elastic ip, as that’s assigned to that particular ec2. (But that would still be under aws) Hmm, that’s why let’s encrypt doesn’t allow bare ip I guess
